# Finding a property of jQuery element

Tags: javascript, jquery, prop

I have HTML like this:

```
<div class="icheckbox_flat-aero checked" style="position: relative;">
    <input type="checkbox" class="icheck" id="Checkbox9" name="userAccessNeeded" target="Checkbox6" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
    <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"></ins>
</div>
```

This is my javascript:

```
$('.iCheck-helper').click(function () {  // the element I clicked on
    var parent = $(this).parent(); // gets the div element
    var classNames = parent.find($("input")).prop("target"); // gets the input elements target
    alert(classNames);
});
```

It should work, but it alert undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `parent.find($("input"))` should be `parent.find("input")`, or just `$(this).prev();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should fix it:

```
$('.iCheck-helper').click(function () {
    var parent = $(this).parent(); 
    var classNames = parent.find("input").attr("target");
    alert(classNames);
});
```

changed

```
parent.find($("input")).prop("target");
```

to

```
parent.find("input").attr("target");
```

Here's a demo: http://jsbin.com/evafub/1/edit

Comment: Can you please explain *why* this should fix it?

Comment: There are a few reasons.  It could be as simple as the version of jquery being used.

Comment: There's no such property (nor attribute, in the HTML5 standard) as `target` on an `input` element.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 thanks :) Keep seeing a lot of answers that just say **do this**, without any reasoning behind **why**. Wanted this one to expand a bit more.

Answer (score 3):

This is because there is no such property named `target` in the [DOM interface of the `input` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element).

`input` elements don't have a `target` attribute, only a `formtarget` (and equivalently there's the `formTarget` property). I'm not sure what the purpose of your "target" is in your code, but a formTarget is a reference to an ID of a form:

> The target and formtarget content attributes, if specified, must have values that are valid browsing context names or keywords.
>
> The **target** of an element is the value of the element's formtarget attribute, if the element is a submit button and has such an attribute; or the value of its form owner's target attribute, if it has such an attribute; or, if the Document contains a base element with a target attribute, then the value of the target attribute of the first such base element; or, if there is no such element, the empty string.

If your "target" is for another purpose, use a [data-* attribute](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) to store the value (i.e.`data-target="Checkbox6"`).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `.attr()` here because, `target` is an attribute here

```
var classNames = parent.find("input").attr("target");
```

or

```
var classNames = $(this).prev().attr("target");
```

Comment: You can also avoid using parent by using `$(this).siblings('input.icheck').attr('target');` instead

Comment: @tymeJV input tag is a self closing element

Comment: Always thought you actually had to have the `/>` at the end, apparently not. Ignore me!